# "requested to" vs "requested from"

Tags: grammar

> This document has information about checks to be requested **from** each department.

vs

> This document has information about checks to be requested **to** each department.

Is the usage of both correct?

Downvoter: Any help improving this question?

Comment: "Requested **from**" is correct.

Comment: @BillFranke: Does that mean "requested to" is incorrect or ungrammatical?

Comment: Yes, it's both incorrect & ungrammatical in this sentence. It'd be OK if it were "... checks that each department will be **requested to make**." I'm sure the downvoter thought the question was too basic to ask & could have been answered by a brief web search. Downvoters here don't usually give reasons. There's no improvement that I (**not the downvoter**) can suggest except "do some homework before asking fundamental questions that can probably be answered by a search engine inquiry, or ask them on the [English Language Learner](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) site.

Comment: @BillFranke: Is this fundamental? I [get a lot of hits for requested to](https://www.google.co.jp/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22information+requested+to+the+*%22&oq=%22information+requested+to+the+*%22&gs_l=hp.3...14451.16281.23.16430.14.13.1.0.0.7.232.1815.0j11j1.12.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.NeSiU8Z7gUE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.dGI&fp=4f08207320f14de1&biw=1600&bih=773).

Comment: There's actually some subtlety to this, and I'm working out an answer. In the meantime: _requested to X_ is common, but only when _to X_ is an infinitive or _requested_ is a participle.

Comment: @Jesse, read the hits you got.  They are things like "forward the information requested to the requestor" or "we will provide assistance in obtaining the information requested, to the extent permitted by law."

Comment: They mean different things. There's no issue of grammar as such but contextual significance. Either could be used if and only if the meaning is clear to the reader in the context.

Comment: @Kris: Thanks for the input. I thought that both could be used, but according to the comments and answers, `requested to` is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4):

Only *requested from* is correct.  If you just do a string search of English text (or a Google search) you will find "requested to" a lot, but that is because "to" is such a heavily used word with so many different functions and "requested" does extra duty as the passive, past tense, and participle form of request.  So you might

- *request information and forward the information requested to the police*, or you might
- *use the information requested to convince your boss*. Or perhaps you
- *requested to go on vacation*.

Still, you only request information *from* someone.

Comment: Thanks, useful information. Perhaps `information` was a bad example, how about the hits for [tests requested to the](https://www.google.co.jp/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22tests+requested+to+the+*%22&oq=%22tests+requested+to+the+*%22&gs_l=hp.3...3029.4096.4.4294.4.3.1.0.0.0.120.346.0j3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.qkBl9rcvlR0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.dGI&fp=4f08207320f14de1&biw=787&bih=575)?

Comment: @JesseGood _Information_ isn't the problem here so much as the passive voice, which inverts the clause and strands _checks_ from the prepositional phrase modifying it.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: Thanks Bradd, I understand the problem now.

Comment: It looks like I parsed the sentence differently than you did, OldPro: information for requesting checks, rather than requesting information about checks. Same conclusion, though.

Answer (score 1):

As prepositions, [*from*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from#Preposition) and [*to*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to#Preposition) indicate direction, and [*request*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/request) is not directional like *send* and *receive* are. However, you can request an item *from* somebody (who will provide it to you), or you can request an item *for* somebody (on their behalf): The preposition modifies the item, not the request itself. So in your example,

> This document has information about **checks** to be requested **from each department.**

is correct if you want each department to provide the checks, and

> This document has information about **checks** to be requested **for each department.**

is correct if you're sending the checks to each department.

Comment: By the way, if you meant to request information from each department, rather than checks, you should restructure the sentence so that _information_ isn't so distant from the transitive verb and prepositional phrase.